# How do I optimize my GetChildren method

Tags: c#, recursion, entity-framework-core

**UPDATED**

I have a POCO class that is populated with `_context.Categories.Load()`:

```cs
[Table("bma_ec_categories")]
public class Category
{
    [Key] 
    [Column("category_id")]
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }

    [Column("parent_category_id")]
    public int? ParentCategoryId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Column("category_name")]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string CategoryName { get; set; }
}
```

I can't change the table design. It is basically a `node`.

I also have an ItemService:

```cs
public class ItemService : IItemService
{
    private readonly EntityContext _context;

    public ItemService(EntityContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
        _context.Categories.Load();
    }

    public async Task<IList<EcommerceItem>> GetAllAsync(string customerNumber, string category = "All", int page = 0, int pageSize = 9999)
    {
        if (category == "All")
        {
            var roots = _context.Categories.Local
                .Where(x => x.ParentCategoryId == 0)
                .Select(x => x.CategoryName)
                .ToList();

            foreach (var root in roots)
            {
                GetChildren(root);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            GetChildren(category);
        }

        var items =  await _context.EcommerceItems
            .FromSqlRaw($"SELECT [ItemNumber], [ItemDescription], [Featured], [Category], [Price], [QtyOnHand], [ImageData] FROM [cp].[GetEcommerceItemsView] WHERE [CustomerNumber] = '{customerNumber}'")
            .OrderBy(i => i.ItemNumber)
            .Where(x => _categories.Contains(x.Category))
            .Skip(page * pageSize)
            .Take(pageSize)
            .AsNoTracking()
            .ToListAsync();

        return items;
    }

    private readonly IList<string> _categories = new List<string>();

    // Helper Methods
    private void GetChildren(string catalog)
    {
        _categories.Add(catalog);

        var id = _context.Categories.Local
            .Where(x => x.CategoryName == catalog)
            .Select(x => x.CategoryId)
            .SingleOrDefault();

        var tempList = _context.Categories.Local
            .Where(x => x.ParentCategoryId == id)
            .Select(x => x.CategoryName)
            .ToList();

        
        foreach (var category in tempList)
        {
            GetChildren(category);
        }
        
    }
}
```

My question is: Is there a better way to `GetChildren()`?

Comment: `if (tempList.Any())` is a kind of redundancy.

Comment: What's the point of using FromSqlRaw for such a basic query? Why use EF if even such basic queries are going to be done via raw SQL?

Comment: @BCdotWEB because `[cp].[GetEcommerceItemsView]` is a view that has complex calculations to get things such as price for this particular user. In addition, I have other queries in this Service that use regular EF queries. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: @aepot You are correct, fixed.

Comment: Don't make further editions to the code. It can make possible code review not actual.

Comment: There is [FromSqlInterpolated](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.relationalqueryableextensions.fromsqlinterpolated?view=efcore-5.0) method that much more secure than manual string interpolation.

Comment: Why do you download categories to the client, if then the search for them is carried out to the database?

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov I fixed my source to use  `FromSqlInterpolated`. As far as your last comment, this is not the client this is a web API. The client is a reactjs app. If you care to explain a bit more I would welcome your input.

Comment: Database is a server. Web App is a client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would be very worried about `GetChildren` implementation. I agree what has been mentioned in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11929535/writing-recursive-cte-using-entity-framework-fluent-syntax-or-inline-syntax based on my experience. It is a bad idea to have Linq client side recursive calls.

If Linq have recursive CTE support now (thread above is from 2012) use that.
Or create a view.
Please do not do client side recursive Linq calls.

Comment: CTE support is not directly related to LINQ in any way. It depends on the ORM capabilities. [linq2db](https://linq2db.github.io/articles/sql/CTE.html) has such support.

Comment: @vish I moved my code into the Entity

Comment: @Randy thanks for the update.